# c# object with a ValueChanged event that fires when each property is changed

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

What is the best way to create a class with an event that fires when one of its Properties is changed?  Specifically, how do you convey to any subscribers which Property was changed?

Ex:

```
public class ValueChangedPublisher
{
    private int _prop1;
    private string _prop2;

    public static event ValueChangedHandler(/*some parameters?*/);

    public int Prop1
    {
        get { return _prop1; }
        set
        {
            if (_prop1 != value)
            {
                _prop1 = value;
                ValueChangedHandler(/*parameters?*/);
            }
        }
    }

    public string Prop2
    {
        get { return _prop2; }
        set
        {
            if (_prop2 != value)
            {
                _prop2 = value;
                ValueChangedHandler(/*parameters?*/);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ValueChangedSubscriber
{
    private int _prop1;
    private string _prop2;

    public ValueChangedSubscriber()
    {
        ValueChangedPublisher.ValueChanged += ValueChanged;
    }

    private void ValueChanged(/*parameters?*/)
    {
        /*how does the subscriber know which property was changed?*/
    }
}
```

My goal is to make this as extensible as possible (e.g. I don't want a bunch of huge if/else if/switch statements lumbering around).  Does anybody know of a technique to achieve what I'm looking for?

**EDIT:**
What I'm *really* looking for is how to utilize the `INotifyPropertyChanged` pattern on the subscriber side.  I don't want to do this:

```
private void ValueChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        switch(propertyName)
        {
            case "Prop1":
                _prop1 = _valueChangedPublisher.Prop1;
                break;

            case "Prop2":
                _prop2 = _valueChangedPublisher.Prop2;
                break;

            // the more properties that are added to the publisher, the more cases I
            // have to handle here :/ I don't want to have to do it this way
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not use `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: Never heard of that.  I'll look into it.  Thanks.

Comment: Add a Binding property to your controls. Use that property to specify which propertyName the control should be bound to by string. Then when you receive a notification of the value changing check which controls have a matching binding. Then update the value of those controls accordingly.

Comment: @JeremiahDotNet Does this work with code that is not a Control? If so this is a very good idea. I'm going to post the solution that I ended up using to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to solve my problem. It's a bit large, so maybe not performant, but works for me.

### Edit

See this question for performance details: [C# using properties with value types with Delegate.CreateDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256233/c-sharp-using-properties-with-value-types-with-delegate-createdelegate)

Base Class for publishing property change stuff:

```
public abstract class PropertyChangePublisherBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> _properties;
    private bool _cacheProperties;

    public bool CacheProperties
    {
        get { return _cacheProperties; }
        set
        {
            _cacheProperties = value;

            if (_cacheProperties && _properties == null)
                _properties = new Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>();
        }
    }

    protected PropertyChangePublisherBase(bool cacheProperties)
    {
        CacheProperties = cacheProperties;
    }

    public bool ContainsBinding(PropertyChangedEventHandler handler)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged == null)
            return false;

        return PropertyChanged.GetInvocationList().Contains(handler);
    }

    public object GetPropertValue(string propertyName)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
            throw new ArgumentException("Argument must be the name of a property of the current instance.", "propertyName");

        return ProcessGetPropertyValue(propertyName);
    }

    protected virtual object ProcessGetPropertyValue(string propertyName)
    {
        if (_cacheProperties)
        {
            if (_properties.ContainsKey(propertyName))
            {
                return _properties[propertyName].GetValue(this, null);
            }

            else
            {
                var property = GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
                _properties.Add(propertyName, property);
                return property.GetValue(this, null);
            }
        }

        else
        {
            var property = GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
            return property.GetValue(this, null);
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Base Class for receiving property change stuff:

```
public abstract class PropertyChangeSubscriberBase
{
    protected readonly string _propertyName;
    protected virtual object Value { get; set; }

    protected PropertyChangeSubscriberBase(string propertyName, PropertyChangePublisherBase bindingPublisher)
    {
        _propertyName = propertyName;

        AddBinding(propertyName, this, bindingPublisher);
    }

    ~PropertyChangeSubscriberBase()
    {
        RemoveBinding(_propertyName);
    }

    public void Unbind()
    {
        RemoveBinding(_propertyName);
    }

    #region Static Fields

    private static List<string> _bindingNames = new List<string>();
    private static List<PropertyChangeSubscriberBase> _subscribers = new List<PropertyChangeSubscriberBase>();
    private static List<PropertyChangePublisherBase> _publishers = new List<PropertyChangePublisherBase>();

    #endregion

    #region Static Methods

    private static void PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        string propertyName = args.PropertyName;

        if (_bindingNames.Contains(propertyName))
        {
            int i = _bindingNames.IndexOf(propertyName);
            var publisher = _publishers[i];
            var subscriber = _subscribers[i];

            subscriber.Value = publisher.GetPropertValue(propertyName);
        }
    }

    public static void AddBinding(string propertyName, PropertyChangeSubscriberBase subscriber, PropertyChangePublisherBase publisher)
    {
        if (!_bindingNames.Contains(propertyName))
        {
            _bindingNames.Add(propertyName);
            _publishers.Add(publisher);
            _subscribers.Add(subscriber);

            if (!publisher.ContainsBinding(PropertyChanged))
                publisher.PropertyChanged += PropertyChanged;
        }
    }

    public static void RemoveBinding(string propertyName)
    {
        if (_bindingNames.Contains(propertyName))
        {
            int i = _bindingNames.IndexOf(propertyName);
            var publisher = _publishers[i];

            _bindingNames.RemoveAt(i);
            _publishers.RemoveAt(i);
            _subscribers.RemoveAt(i);

            if (!_publishers.Contains(publisher))
                publisher.PropertyChanged -= PropertyChanged;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Actual class to use for subscribing to property change stuff:

```
public sealed class PropertyChangeSubscriber<T> : PropertyChangeSubscriberBase
{
    private PropertyChangePublisherBase _publisher;

    public new T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (base.Value == null)
                return default(T);

            if (base.Value.GetType() != typeof(T))
                throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("Property {0} on object of type {1} does not match the type Generic type specified {2}.", _propertyName, _publisher.GetType(), typeof(T)));

            return (T)base.Value;
        }

        set { base.Value = value; }
    }

    public PropertyChangeSubscriber(string propertyName, PropertyChangePublisherBase bindingPublisher)
        : base(propertyName, bindingPublisher)
    {
        _publisher = bindingPublisher;
    }
}
```

Here is an example of the Class with properties that you wish to be notified about:

```
public class ExamplePublisher: PropertyChangedPublisherBase
{
    private string _id;
    private bool _testBool;

    public string Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _id) return;
            _id = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }

    public bool TestBool
    {
        get { return _testBool; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(_testBool)) return;
            _testBool = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged("TestBool");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of the Class that will be notified when the properties in the class above change:

```
public class ExampleReceiver
{
    public PropertyChangeSubscriber<string> Id { get; set; }
    public PropertyChangeSubscriber<bool> TestBool { get; set; }

    public MyExampleClass(PropertyChangePublisherBase publisher)
    {
        Id = new PropertyChangeSubscriber<string>("Id", publisher);
        TestBool = new PropertyChangeSubscriber<bool>("TestBool", publisher);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

.NET provides the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx). Inherit and implement it:

```
public class ValueChangedPublisher : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _prop1;
    private string _prop2;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler ValueChangedHandler;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public int Prop1
    {
        get { return _prop1; }
        set
        {
            if (_prop1 != value)
            {
                _prop1 = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public string Prop2
    {
        get { return _prop2; }
        set
        {
            if (_prop2 != value)
            {
                _prop2 = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```