# C# using properties with value types with Delegate.CreateDelegate

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates, primitive, value-type

Using Jon Skeet's article [Making reflection fly and exploring delegates](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates.aspx) as a guide, I am trying to use the Delegate.CreateDelegate method to duplicate properties as delegates.  Here's an example class:

```
public class PropertyGetter
{
    public int Prop1 {get;set;}
    public string Prop2 {get;set;}

    public object GetPropValue(string propertyName)
    {
        var property = GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetGetMethod();
        propertyDelegate = (Func<object>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<object>), this, property);

        return propertyDelegate();
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is when I call `GetPropValue` and pass in `"Prop1"` as the parameter, I get an `ArgumentException` on the call to `Delegate.CreateDelegate` with the message `"Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type."`  This happens when using any property that returns a primitive/value type including structs.

Does anybody know a way to be able to use both reference and value types here?

Comment: Do you just want the value of the property, or do you actually want to return a delegate that represents the getter.  If the former, just use `PropertyInfo.GetValue`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fundamentally your general approach isn't possible.  The reason you're able to take all non-value types and treat them as a `Func<object>` is by relying on contravariance (`Func<T>` is contravariant with respect to `T`).  As per the language specs, contravariance does not support value types.

Of course, the problem is easier if you just don't rely on using that approach.

If you just want to get the value use the `PropertyInfo.GetValue` method:

```
public object GetPropValue(string name)
{
    return GetType().GetProperty(name).GetValue(this);
}
```

If you want to return a `Func<object>` which will fetch the value whenever it's called, just create a lambda around that reflection call:

```
public Func<object> GetPropValue2(string name)
{
    return () => GetType().GetProperty(name).GetValue(this);
}
```

Comment: I got all wrapped up in replicating Jon's performance enhancements and didn't even think to use PropertyInfo.GetValue. Funny thing is, I tested the performance of GetValue, the method I mentioned in the question, as well as direct property access using a Stopwatch and discovered that GetValue is faster than the method I used in the question. Thanks.